# Deployment failing after deleting API Gateway. How to recover?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, serverless-framework

After I removed the API gateway manually via the aws console because changing the configuration in my serverless.yml file didn’t seem to change the Gateway configuration anymore.

Now deployment fails with " An error saying: **ApiGatewayMethodGet - Template error: API Gateway RestAPI dj1ivqgipb doesn't exist**".

I understand that this is an error caused by me, but can anyone please hint me into the direction of how to recover from this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzr8S.png

Comment: If you can delete everything, then do it, even if have to do it manually in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did was to go to API Gateway -> Custom domain names -> then I reconfigure API mapping from pointing to the old deleted API to then point to the existing API that I just created in the cli... Then now I can re-deploy my serverless application.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Sjh.png